# Switching between view controllers, iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been working on a weather app for several weeks now.I currently have 4 view controllers setup and functioning. Everything is currently linked to my tab bar controller however I need more space on the bar and 3 of the view controllers are similar. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.The 3 like view controllers are forecast controllers, one is a current conditions, one is a extended forecast and the third is a weekend view. what I would like to do is have the current controller linked to the tab bar (easy enough) and have the option to switch the views to the other options from the current view. I tried adding another tab bar controller but I didn't like the way it looked with two tab bar controllers. I added a picture so you can see how it is currently setup, basically I want to elliminate the last 2 tabs and access them through the 2nd tab. Any suggestions on the best most effective method to accomplish this goal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just curious - where are you getting your radar data?

Comment: Ah, I was hoping you wouldn't say that. Expensive!

Comment: There are more expensive then that, I have a source for level III tiles raw $$$$$.weatherunderground isn't bad.

Comment: @Rickay have you implemented CLLocation to draw the users location for map position or forecast area?

Comment: Yes, but you really only need MKMapView for that. Also, I have used wunderground, but the resolution of the radar overlays isn't great.

Comment: @Rickay I'm not using MKMapView, I'm using a different framework witch need to be setup to use an alternative. Right now it only pulls for the location city/state/country I assigned to it for testing purposes.

Comment: @JoeYetter Show us a screen shot of the forecast screen.

Comment: Well then yes, you will need to use the `CLLocationManager` class to acquire the user's current position. It's relatively easy to set up: http://idevzilla.com/2011/01/05/where-am-i-know-how-to-get-your-location-using-cllocationmanager/

Comment: @robmayoff I added the view in the original post (one view anyway)

Comment: @Rickay Is there a way I can contact you directly?

Comment: Check my bio for my email contact.

Comment: @Rickay don't see email contact in your Bio.

Answer (score 4):

This is really more of a UI design question than a programming question… but I will put some programming in anyway.

I suggest you put the three forecasts in a single, paging-enabled scroll view.  Then you just need one tab, and you can let the user swipe between the forecasts:

[image: paging weather view]

You can also implement this scrolling with a `UIPageViewController` on iOS 6 by setting its `transitionStyle` to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.

To make the user aware that there are multiple forecasts available, you could add a [`UIPageControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html), if you can find room for it on that rather busy forecast screen.

Another way to make the user aware of the other forecast pages is to bounce the scroll view when it appears.  This is the programming comes in!

Do this in the forecast tab's view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self bounceScrollViewIfNeeded];
}

- (void)bounceScrollViewIfNeeded {
    if (scrollView_.contentOffset.x != 0)
        return;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        scrollView_.contentOffset = CGPointMake(20, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished && !scrollView_.tracking) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
                scrollView_.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
            } completion:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

This code makes the scroll view bounce a little when the forecast tab appears, *if* the scroll view is showing the leftmost page.  You might also want to stop doing the bounce after the user has seen it a few times.  Anyway, it looks like this:

[image: bounce]

If the user tries to start dragging while the bounce is happening, you need to cancel the animations.  You can do that by assigning your view controller as the scroll view's delegate, and implementing this delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [scrollView_.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"bounds"];
}
```

I don't think there's an easy way to do a bounce with a `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll give this a try when I get home from the hospital (new baby coming today).

Comment: One question, the bottom portion of the detail view show already has a scroll built in for the hourly forecast, will this interfere?

Comment: Try it and see.  If it interferes, come back and we'll figure out a solution.

Comment: Since i'm very new implementation is not always easy, rely on tutorials, books, etc. I can't seem to find a tutorial on implementing this into my existing project using storyboards. Are you aware of any good tutorials for my situation or do you have any steps to follow. additionally I added 2 blank view controllers to test using swipe gesture and it works fine to flip back and forth but if I try adding this to the forecast controllers it does not work, is there a particular reason why?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using a [`UISegmentedControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) at the top of the view. If the views are similar enough that they can be displayed with only minor variation using the same `UIViewController` class, this is an easy solution.

If the views differ enough that it would be inconvenient to control the views in the same `UIViewController`, I like to use container views, although they are only available in iOS 6. You can embed a `UIViewController` using an embed segue into the container view's `UIView`. In the `segmentedControlValueChanged:` method, just hide the container views for the other segments and unhide the container view that is currently selected.

Comment: I think the segmented control may interfere with the content, I'm looking into using a page view controller to move between the forecast but I am definitely struggling with it. I'm new and learning this may be harder then a foreign language!